# $_SESSION['username'] not working

Tags: php, session

This is panel login:

```
<?php include('header.php'); 
    $login=mysql_query("select * from user")or die(mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($login);
    $level = $row[3];

    session_start();            
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        if ($level == '1')
            {
                header('location:admin/index.php');
            }

        if ($level == '2')
            {
                header('location:member/index.php');
            }
    }

    ?>

        <body>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
        <center>
            </br>
            </br>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="header">
                    <div class="alert alert-success"><label>Login to the System</label></div>
                </div>

                <form method="post"> 
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>User Name</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" required></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Password</label></td>
                        <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button></td>
                    </tr>


                </table>
                </form>

                <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                    $username=$_POST['username'];
                    $password=($_POST['password']);

                    $login=mysql_query("select * from user where user_name='$username' and user_password='$password'")or die(mysql_error());
                    $count=mysql_num_rows($login);

                    $row=mysql_fetch_row($login);
                    $level = $row[3];


                    if ($count > 0){

                    $_SESSION['username']=$row[1];
                        if ($level == 1)
                            {
                                header('location:admin/index.php');
                            }

                        if ($level == 2)
                            {
                                header('location:member/index.php');
                            }

                    }

                    else{ ?>
                    <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Error Login! Wrong Combination of Username and Password!");
                    </script> -->
                    <div class="alert alert-error">Error login! Please check your username or password</div>
                    <?php
                    }}
                    ?>




            </div>


        </center>
    </div>
    </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I logged in with the correct information but the system is not forwarded to the member's page. $_SESSION['username'] not working. I tried all the solutions I can find on the internet, none of them worked. I'm out ideas as to why this isn't working. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

I used this code: can you help me fix it ? Thank you very much

http://vinhomegroup.com/post2/feeds.zip

Comment: Are you sure it's set? `var_dump($_SESSION);` does it show? Can you show us the code where you are setting it?

Comment: ... Have you considered not destroying the session first?

Comment: Why are you starting your session, destroying it, then starting it again? You will **never** be able to access `username` because you destroyed that session and never set the `username` again.

Comment: The header properly looks like `header('Location: admin/index.php');` and you should keep in mind that it does NOT implicitly stop the script. Its execution keeps going until `exit;` or end of script. You cannot send headers after or during http body btw.

Comment: You can't set an http header after any output has been done, so in your case the `header()` won't work.

Comment: `session_start();session_destroy();session_start();` - Why????

Answer (score 2):

```
session_destroy();
```

After this call it's not so strange there's nothing left in `$_SESSION`.

Apart from this there's a lot of things awfully wrong in your logic, I mean:

```
$login=mysql_query("select * from user")or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_row($login);
$level = $row[3];
```

You're selecting a random user, what the hell is `$level` supposed to be containing here?

Comment: I used this code: http://vinhomegroup.com/post2/feeds.zip can you help me fix it ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You are destroying your session before reading the variable.

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_start();
```

Therefore you will not be able to access your `$_SESSION` variables.

**Remove the two first lines of the snippet above and this will be fine.**

Answer (score 0):

You destroy session and afterward you want to check if exists.

You must process the form at another page or simply protect `session_desytroy` will not execute after you send from.

```
if (empty($_POST['submit'])){
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    session_start();  
}
```

If you put it into the condidion, it will not destroy your session after form is sent.

I personally think ist is pointless to `set`, `destroy` and `set` again session. Simply do

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You destroyed your session  in `session_destroy();`

```
    <?php include('header.php'); 
//Where are the user details to select the user? Should not it be like?
        $sql = "select * from `user` WHERE `username ` = 'something' AND `password` = 'something' LIMIT 1";
        $login=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
        $row=mysql_fetch_row($login);
        $level = $row[3];

    //Start a session first
        session_start();

    //Set session username here
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row[username-array-key]
            if ($level == '1')
                {
                    header('location:admin/index.php');
                }

            if ($level == '2')
                {
                    header('location:member/index.php');
                }


        ?>
```